# Apache2 running ok but localhost not opening on ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, localhost

I have installed apache2 on ubuntu (12), asfter starting the service I enter localhost in the web browser but I get:" Ooups!Error loading localhost" and I get a blank page. Same with 127.0.0.1.

Verified the var/www/ folder and the index.html file is in place. 
One more thing, if I do "netstat -a | more", the /wwww folder is not listed, see the image attached.

What could be wrong?
Thanks!

[image]